# `rewrite at` fails when `rewrite` works

Tags: coq

When I type `rewrite <- […]`, the command replaces two occurences of the lemma in the goal, when I write `rewrite <- […] at 2`, it rewrites the second instance.

However, when I write `rewrite <- […] at 1`, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Tactic failure: Unable to satisfy the rewriting constraints.
Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
[…]
```

More specifically:

```coq
Goal: (e) · (e') = e.
Hypothesis inverse_left : forall x : G, (inv x)·x = e.

rewrite <- (inverse_left x) at 1.
```

**EDIT**:

The minimal (in the end working) example:

```coq
(* Required for `rewrite at`. *)
Require Setoid.

Section stackoverflow.

Variable G : Set.
Variable prod : G -> G -> G.
(* I have no idea which level to choose *)
(* 80 is too much (binds weaker than `=`) *)
(* 0 is too little *)
Infix "·" := prod (at level 30).
Variable e : G.
Variable inv : G -> G.

Hypothesis inverse_left : forall x : G, (inv x)·x = e.
Goal forall x e' : G, e·e' = e.
intros x e'. rewrite <- (inverse_left x) at 1.
```

Coq version:

```
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl5 (February 2015)
Architecture Linux running Unix operating system
Gtk version is 2.24.25
This is coqide.opt (opt is the best one for this architecture and OS)
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to say what could be going on without more information. Could you add more code from your development to your question?

Comment: Please post complete code that we can run on our machine (i.e. supply definitions for `inv`, `G`, etc.). What version of Coq are you using? And post the complete error.

Comment: Thanks for your help! As said below, creating a minimal working example in a different tab of the IDE helped me find the "error", and that restarting fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a minimal testing example to post here, I noticed that the minimal example *worked*. However, double-checking the original code, still gave the error mentioned above.

The solution to the problem was rather banal – after re-opening the seemingly errornous code and rechecking, the previously rejected proof was accepted.

I suppose this happened due to the fact that `coqide` keeps open the `coq` instance it uses for checking the proof, resulting in a reject, because the `coq` instance was probably faulty due to prior input.

TL;DR: **Solution: Reopen `coqide` in order to fix this problem.**